# Adding a number to command parameter and outputting it

Tags: arithmetic

I have a command that takes a single parameter. I want to add a constant number to that parameter and include it in the output. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
\newcommand*{\label}[1]{%
    Here is the sum: {#1 + 20}
}

% elsewhere...
\label{22) % should output "Here is the sum: 42"
```

What's the simplest way of achieving this? Having googled a bit, I see talk of `calc`, `fp`, and other packages. Is there nothing that is simple and built-in to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of packages that can help you perform calculations or arithmetic. Here's its easy to use `\inteval` (from [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp)) to `eval`uate an `int`eger expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*{\outputsum}[1]{%
  Here is the sum: \inteval{#1 + 20}%
}

\begin{document}

\outputsum{22} % should output "Here is the sum: 42"

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use a package and your calculations are fairly elementary, then you can also use

```
\newcommand*{\outputsum}[1]{%
  Here is the sum: \number\numexpr#1 + 20\relax%
}
```

For sums using decimals, the above won't work as a `num`eric `expr`ession assumes integer calculations.

And let's not use `\label`, as that's typically reserved for cross referencing.

Comment: Thanks! The `\numexpr` approach was fine for my needs.